# How to retrieve Eclipse Sisu created bean from an instance that has been instantiated with a new ()

Tags: eclipse, dependency-injection, eclipse-plugin, sisu

I'm trying to integrate kind of 'DI' within my Eclipse 3.x like project.

So I defined some 'business' beans like this:

```
@Named
class A{...}

@Named class B{ @Inject private A a;
public void doSmtg() { //use a
}
```

And finally I have an Eclipse AbstractHandler class (registered by a plugin.xml extension point) where i want to Inject the B bean.

```
public class UIHandler extends AbstractHandler implements IHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
// I want to get my B bean where A is injected
}}
```

Is it feasible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Sisu Activator, I used the SisuTracker code and now use that snippet to get a bean:

```
this.resourceToAssetFinder = (ILocator<R, Asset>) Activator.getPlugin().findLocator(Activator.getPlugin().getBundle().getBundleContext()).locate(Key.get(IResourceToAssetLocator.class)).iterator().next().getValue();
```

This way, all beans are loaded in my bundle's classpath.

Side info, the needed dependencies to bootstrap Sisu are:

```
 <artifact>
    <id>com.google.guava:guava:${com.google.guava_guava.version}</id>
</artifact>
<artifact>
    <id>com.google.inject:guice:${com.google.inject_guice.version}</id>
    <transitive>false</transitive>
</artifact>
<artifact>
        <id>com.google.inject.extensions:guice-multibindings:${com.google.inject.extensions_guice-multibindings.version}</id>
        <transitive>false</transitive>
</artifact>
<artifact>      <id>org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.inject:${org.eclipse.sisu.version}</id>
</artifact>
```